# How to retrieve column total when rows are paginated?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a column "price" in a table and I used a pagination script to generate the data displayed.  Now the pagination is working perfectly however I am trying to have a final row in my HTML table to show the total of all the price.  So I wrote a script to do just that with a foreach loop and it sort of works where it does give me the total of all the price summed up together however it is the sum of all the rows, even the ones that are on following pages.  How can I retrieve just the sum of the rows displayed within the pagination?

Here is the query..

```
SELECT 
purchase_log.id,
purchase_log.date_purchased,
purchase_log.total_cost,
purchase_log.payment_status,
cart_contents.product_name,
members.first_name, members.last_name,
members.email FROM purchase_log LEFT
JOIN cart_contents ON purchase_log.id
= cart_contents.purchase_id LEFT JOIN members ON purchase_log.member_id =
members.id GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,30";
```

Comment: Kind of hard to help... If your pagination is done through PHP, use a variable to sum only rows displayed (in the loop) in that page? Are the following pages "real" pages or hidden div/tbody?

Comment: Yes its done through PHP and yes they are real queries and pages.  Nothing is hidden.  And when you say use a variable I assume you mean use sum(column) as total?

Answer (score 2):

Just use MySQL function **FOUND_ROWS()**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to append LIMIT 0,20 to a mysql query this will only sum total the current pageinated displayed results.

I assume you use a LIMIT to pageinate the results, unless you array the data into a grid in which case you'll need to post code.

Comment: Yes the query already has LIMIT 0,30...I am using the same query to display the paginated results as with the total. I use this to get the total currently. {<?php foreach ($purchase as $items) :
   $total += $items['purchase_log.total_cost'];
  endforeach;
  ?>}

Comment: and if you print_r() out your results and view them, you're only getting the requested rows and no others?  (just to make sure you're getting the correct data back)

Comment: It turns out I had to just change purchase_log.total_cost to total_cost and it worked...Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What about using the mysql SUM function in your mySQL query?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: I tried that but it throws off the cost in each row...perhaps have a look at the query?  I updated the post..

Comment: It turns out I had to just change purchase_log.total_cost to total_cost and it worked...Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize total to zero so that it can display the sum of the records that you are fetching with limit.

```
<?php 
$total = 0;
foreach ($purchase as $items) : 
$total += $items['purchase_log.total_cost']; 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It turns out I had to just change purchase_log.total_cost to total_cost and it worked...Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Rick If this answer was helpful in answering your question, please accept it.  It removes the question from the unanswered list, and shows appreciation for their time.