# Anyway to append the colmn data in the rows mysql?

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have this query.

> ```
> SELECT purchase_log.id, purchase_log.date_purchased,
> ```
>
> purchase_log.total_cost,
>   purchase_log.payment_status,
>   cart_contents.product_name,
>   members.first_name, members.last_name,
>   members.email FROM purchase_log LEFT
>   JOIN cart_contents ON purchase_log.id
>   = cart_contents.purchase_id LEFT JOIN members ON purchase_log.member_id =
>   members.id

And in the column cart_contents.product_name, I want to string/append together the varchar values..So for example each row that returns has Row1 Col product_name = green and row2 Col product_name orange...etc  but I would like it to return green,orange...etc..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

> SELECT purchase_log.id,
>   purchase_log.date_purchased,
>
> ```
> purchase_log.total_cost, purchase_log.payment_status,
> ```
>
> group_concat(cart_contents.product_name) as product_name,
>   members.first_name, members.last_name,
>   members.email FROM purchase_log LEFT
>   JOIN cart_contents ON purchase_log.id
>   = cart_contents.purchase_id LEFT JOIN members ON purchase_log.member_id =
>   members.id 
>   group by cart_contents.product_name

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I don't really understand what that does but I am not trying to concat multiple columns..I am trying to concat one column with multiple rows...

Comment: Well, it is for concating multiple rows of a column. Well i am editing my answer for your reference. Please check if it works.

Comment: Yes that worked...You are a MYSQL genius!!  wish I knew half of what you know...I didn't think it would work because I read up on concat() and that seems to just concat multiple columns.. But I guess "group" changes things...Perhaps you can help with this one as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529527/how-to-retrieve-column-total-when-rows-are-paginated